# Is it possible to direct audio output to input (mic) using Python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm looking for a software solution (preferably in Python, such as using PyAudio or other libraries) that does the following on a Windows machine: redirect audio from output (speakers) to input (microphone). Basically, send sound to 2 devices at once, one would be speakers so I can hear the sound, and the other microphone so software that works with mic can hear that sound at once. Note that I'm using a headset.

Can the above goal be achieved in a programmable way, preferably in Python? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For looping back audio there will need to be a virtual audio device installed to loop back audio. For windows you could use something like [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html) After that you could 100% programmatically choose where the audio stream in your programme is to be directed.